# How can i use group by clause on case statement aliasing in tsql?

Tags: t-sql, azure-synapse

I have a case statement in my query with a aliasing and im trying to display it with group-by clause but i keep on getting the error "Invalid Column Name *(case statement aliasing)*"

Code

```
Select column 1,
       column 2,
       column 3,
       Case When .... then ...
            When .... then ...
            When .... then ... 
            else ... as X
From table1,
     table 2,
     table 3
where condition 1,
      condition 2,
      condition 3
group by column 1,
         column 2,
         X,
         column 3;
```

Output : Invalid Column name 'X'.

Comment: Either repeat the case statement, use a derived table or a CTE

Comment: `CASE` **expression** by the way; T-SQL doesn't support `Switch` (`Case`) statements.

Comment: @Larnu thanks - I know the terminology :)  just had a lax moment.

Comment: That was more aimed at the OP, @Stu . :)

Comment: @Larnu ah. Oops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include the whole case statement in the group by clause instead of using the alias. So

```
group by column 1,
         column 2,
       Case When .... then ...
            When .... then ...
            When .... then ... 
            else ... ,
         column 3;
```